# Java- updating JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I've got a JTree which I'm using to display some (unsurprisingly) hierarchical data. Part of the spec is that the user can change the data source (atm it's just between files). Now, when this happens, I can rebuild the data and the tree nodes with no problem. But, I'm having substantial difficulties getting the tree to update the changes. I tried removing it from it's scrollpane and replacing with a new JTree, but I didn't see any such. I've tried removing all from the JTree and didn't see any effect.

How can I make the JTree display changes after it's been constructed?
Ninjedit: Yes, I did call updateUI().

Another edit:
I also wanted to replace the tree's current data with my new data. However, I don't see any methods that will take the DefaultMutableTreeNode that I constructed with. Even if I just remove the JTree and call updateUI on it's containing ScrollPane, nothing happens. Or if I use repaint instead.

Comment: How are you creating the JTree?

Comment: By building the nodes, then creating the JTree directly from them.

Comment: updateUI() is for changing the Look and Feel on the fly and has nothing to do with repainting a component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be that the proper events (the JTree internal events) are not being fired. For example, you can add nodes either by using `node.add(...)` or even better, `model.insertNodeInto(...)` (assuming you're using the `DefaultTreeModel`). In this case, the latter method is preferred as it will fire appropriate events that will cause the view (the JTree) to update correctly. It's possible that your problem isn't with redrawing the UI, but in fact notifying the view that the model has changed.
So, I would suggest looking in to how you're dynamically modifying your JTree, and if possible I'd suggest using the `DefaultTreeModel` as your model to drive the view.

And just to make sure, you've read through [the Sun JTree tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html), right?

Comment: Turns out that the defaultTreeModel contained all the functions I needed. The JTree just didn't provide any useful methods to get at them. Once I made the JTree from a model and grabbed the model, all was easy.

Comment: Excellent! It pays to be model-driven.